# Объясните как использовать SwitchTransition в react-transition-group

Tags: reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

Документация по теме очень скудна, хотелось бы чтобы кто-нибудь разжевал подробно как использовать данный компонент, а именно:

1. Какие у него props
2. Что принимает в качестве children
3. Как производится задание классов анимации

В общем, как его использовать на практике. Например, для переходов между компонентами react-router-dom

Код модуля react-transition-group: [GitHub](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group)

Документация: [SwitchTransition](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/switch-transition)

Answer (score 0):

В официальной документации FadeTransition - это обычная CSSTranstion, упакованная в компонент react:

```
const FadeTransition = props => (
  <CSSTransition
    {...props}
    classNames='fade'
    timeout={350}
    appear
    addEndListener={(node, done) => {
      node.addEventListener('transitionend', done, false);
    }}
  />
);
```

Таким образом, чтобы использовать SwitchTranstion, например с react-router-dom:

```
const App = props => {
  return (
      <Fragment>
        <Navbar />
        <div className='container'>
          <SwitchTransition mode='out-in'>
            <FadeTransition key={props.history.location.pathname}>
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                <Route exact path='/about' component={About} />
              </Switch>
            </FadeTransition>
          </SwitchTransition>
        </div>
      </Fragment>
  );
};

export default withRouter(App);
```

CSS код:

```
.fade-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.fade-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: 350ms ease;
}

.fade-exit {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: 350ms ease;
}

.fade-exit-active {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: 350ms;
}
```

---

### Следовательно, отвечая на свои вопросы:

1. В качестве props у SwitchTranstion: mode="out-in" или mode="in-out", как и во vue.js означает как будут отображаться компоненты при анимации
2. В качестве children принимает последовательно отображаемые компоненты react, обёрнутые в CSSTransition
3. Задание классов анимации производится стандартным для CSSTransition способом в css-стилях, как видно из приведённого выше кода